# Excel vba to insert conditional format if cell in Sheet1 does not match same cell in Sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried to program this so when I create a workbook which is saved as an xlsx file, the vba in the workbook I am copying the data from copies conditional formatting to sheet1 of the new workbook. I need it to have the formula A1 <> Sheet2!A1 then text font is red. and then the next cell would be B1 <> Sheet2"B1 text font is red.

I need this to be copied to the active range. I tried this code, but it does not work for me. Have spent 2 weeks trying to find answers for this with no joy.

```
Application.CutCopyMode =False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=A1<>Sheet2!A1"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color =-16776961
    .TintAndShade =0
EndWith

Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue =False
Selection.Copy
Range("A1:S200").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Which sheet needs to show the red text? Sheet 2 or Sheet 1?

Comment: sheet1 needsto show red text. i was hoping to have sheet2 hidden

Comment: It occured to me as I was fashioning the answer that the problem is really one of object qualification. You're dealing with multiple workbooks and worksheets. When you say `Range("A1:S200')` in your code, Excel has to guess what which Worksheet you want. It's my belief that Excel chooses the ActiveWorksheet. I have added some notes to my answer to help you write code that tells Excel exactly which worksheet should get the changes. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all of your code with this:

```
Dim newCondition As FormatCondition 'Red text if Sheet1 cell doesn't match Sheet2 cell.
Dim conditionFormula As String      'Formula for the format condition

' Compare each cell using indirect addressing of the current row and column. Result is
' true if the sheet cells don't match, false if they do.
conditionFormula = "=(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),1,1,""Sheet1"")) <>" & _
                   "  INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),1,1,""Sheet2"")))"

' Create the condition and get a pointer to it.
Set newCondition = Range("A1:S200").FormatConditions.Add( _
                                    Type:=xlExpression, _
                                    Formula1:=conditionFormula)

' Add the formatting, priority, stop rule to the condition.
With newCondition
    .SetFirstPriority
    With .Font
        .Color = -16776961  ' Red
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    .StopIfTrue = False
End With

' Clear the pointer
Set newCondition = Nothing
```

Naturally, the `conditionFormula` string declaration isn't necessary, but I like to write code that is easy to read and understand later. I've had too many times where I've come back later and wondered what #@%*&! I was trying to do.

Note that you could use `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` instead of `Range("A1:S200")`. That will guarantee that you always get all the cells that have data.

Finally, I have not fully qualified the `Range()` method in my code. Therefore Excel will guess which sheet you want to use. It might be better to be more explicit about which workbook and sheet you're talking about.  So, for example, when you create your new workbook, do something like this:

```
Dim newWorkbook As Workbook

Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(.... whatever you do here...)
```

Then, you can replace `Range("A1:S200")` with

```
newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:S200")
```

or even

```
newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
```

Hope all that helps. Sorry for the length.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm done editing it. Quite a few changes from my original answer, but most of those changes are clarifications and style changes. The core is the same.

Comment: Thanks that worked great. I was asked if it was possible to create conditional format for the same but add borders to the the next row below where the new text was added. so if cell a11 had text added then cells a12 b12 c12 d12 would automatically have borders. and if a12 had text added a13 b13 c13 d13 would have black boders added